# Amazon DynamoDB via CloudFormation - point in time recovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, database-backups, pitr

Is it possible to specify **Point In Time Recovery** for an Amazon DynamoDB table created via CloudFormation? I've been looking through the docs and [user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html) and haven't found anything useful yet.

Comment: you can keep taking snapshot of DynamoDB; and get to a PIT recovery as and when needed.. Just like RDS

Comment: PITR is available via AWS UI. Specifically looking for how to specify this value in CloudFormation script

Comment: I don't think CloudFormation supports this feature yet. CloudFormation support for new features generally takes time.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 - you're probably right. CLI doesn't support it yet either.

Answer (score 45):

[This is now possible](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html) with cloud formation by adding a `PointInTimeRecoverySpecification` to your cloud formation template.

Example:

```
  Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
  Properties:
    TableName: MyTable
    PointInTimeRecoverySpecification:
      PointInTimeRecoveryEnabled: true
    ...
```